# NOTIFY vs. pg_notify

Tags: postgresql

I write a DB LISTENing program something like as shown here (Example 3)==> https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/libpq-example.html

I have a problem with pg_notify such that;

```
NOTIFY channel
```

==> works fine, C program catches the signal

whereas

```
SELECT pg_notify('channel','This is a test');
```

==> Program can't catch anything.

Any idea?
Note: My Version is PostgreSQL 10.5

Answer (score 4):

In `NOTIFY Channel`, 'Channel' is treated as an SQL identifier, and will automatically be transformed to lower case if not surrounded by double quotes, like `NOTIFY "Channel"`.  This is usual PostgreSQL behavior.  The arguments to pg_notify are strings, not SQL identifiers, so they are case-preserved.

Answer (score 2):

I think, I found the solution. If I use lower characters in the channel name, pg_notify and corresponding C program works well, but for the upper case channel name, it doesn't work.